# Dice roll with a 50% chance of rolling 6

Tags: java, random

So I made this method of rolling a dice 100 times with a 50% chance of rolling 6.
Basic idea is that there are 50% odd numbers and 50% even numbers between 1 and 6, so if an even number is rolled, system prints 6 else it prints a random number between 1 and 5. Do you think this is correct?

```
public static void printDiceRolls(Random randGenerator) {
    for (int i=0; i < 30; i++) {
        int temp;
        temp = randGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (temp%2 == 0) {
            temp = 6;
        }
        else
            temp = randGenerator.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.print(" " + temp + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why first generating a random number between `1` and `6`? Why not `0` and `1`?

Comment: There is no need to generate a number between 1 and 6. You can just generate one between 0 and 1, and if it's 0, print 6, and if it isn't, do your second step.

Comment: Possibly [related](https://www.random.org/analysis/dilbert.jpg).

Comment: Furthermore you can easily generate one random number to boost performance...

Comment: A literal implementation of your suggested solution might produce the probabilities that you want, but it would not simulate an actual die which were weighted such that 50% of the time it landed on 6.

Comment: What a delightfully eccentric way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Generate a random number between 1 and 10, inclusive on both ends.  If the number be 1 to 5, you rolled that number, otherwise, you rolled 6.  Note that there are 5 chances in this scheme to roll a 6 (i.e. 50%), and 5 *total* chances to roll 1 through 5 (i.e. the other 50%).

```
Random random = new Random();
int roll = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
if (roll > 5) {
    System.out.println("You rolled a 6");
}
else {
    System.out.println("You rolled a " + roll);
}
```

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman No, I disagree with you.  For 10 rolls, on average 50% of them would be 6, and the other 50% would be every other number (1-5), with each of those other numbers having an equal chance.

Comment: But, the op wants 50% time the 6 being diced... not on. avg. 50 ... in which case your code doesn't ensure 50% 6 being diced always....

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman: That's a weird interpretation, and also not what the OP's own code does.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate number from 1 to 10 and print 6 if its bigger than 6

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
    int temp = randGenerator.nextInt(10) + 1;
    if (temp > 6) {
        temp = 6;
    }
    System.out.print(" "+temp+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dice roll with a 50% chance of rolling 6
>
> The following method ensures 50% of the dice being 6 but they won't
>   come in alternative manner... I think this is the best way to ensure
>   that 6 being diced exactly 50% times but not in alternating sequence
>   which makes the result more believable, in my opinion.

In my view you only need to do it:

```
public static void naturalDicingWithVariablePercentageOfSix(int totalDice,int probability)
{
    Random rand=new Random();
    List<Integer> diceList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println(""+( (int)(100/probability))+"% times that six being diced \n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<totalDice;i++)
    {
        if(i%probability==0)
            diceList.add(6);
        else
            diceList.add(rand.nextInt(5)+1);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(diceList);


    int notSixCount=0;
    int sixCount=0;
    for(Integer diceVal:diceList)
    {
        if(diceVal!=6)
            notSixCount++;
        else
            sixCount++;

        System.out.print(diceVal+" ");

    }
    System.out.println("\n\n Not 6 being diced : "+notSixCount+" times "+" and Six being diced :"+sixCount+"\n\n");
}
```

Input:

```
    naturalDicingWithVariablePercent6(100,2); // 50% times 6
    naturalDicingWithVariablePercent6(100,3); // 33% times 6
    naturalDicingWithVariablePercent6(100,4); // 25% times 6
    naturalDicingWithVariablePercent6(100,5); // 20% times 6
    naturalDicingWithVariablePercent6(100,6); // 16.67% times 6
```

> Output:

50% times that six being diced

4 3 6 6 3 5 4 6 2 1 6 6 6 6 1 6 6 4 3 5 6 6 5 4 2 5 6 2 1 6 5 5 1 6 6 6 2 6 4 6 6 4 6 6 6 6 2 1 6 3 6 4 3 5 6 6 5 6 6 6 6 6 4 2 6 3 3 6 3 6 6 6 3 5 2 5 6 6 3 2 6 6 6 5 4 6 4 4 3 6 5 4 6 1 6 6 6 6 5 6

Not 6 being diced : 50 times  and Six being diced :50

33% times that six being diced

2 6 1 6 5 2 1 5 6 5 6 3 3 2 1 3 5 3 6 6 4 4 2 6 6 1 1 4 2 6 6 3 6 2 6 5 6 4 1 3 6 4 1 1 2 6 5 6 6 6 2 4 2 2 3 6 4 3 4 1 6 4 4 2 4 6 6 4 5 4 6 6 2 4 4 5 3 6 6 6 3 6 6 1 2 4 1 4 6 6 6 5 4 4 5 5 6 2 3 6

Not 6 being diced : 66 times  and Six being diced :34

25% times that six being diced

6 1 3 4 6 4 4 2 4 1 6 3 6 1 1 3 3 5 3 4 1 2 3 3 6 3 3 4 5 5 2 6 5 2 3 1 1 4 4 6 5 4 2 3 5 6 3 4 6 4 6 6 5 6 6 5 1 6 6 6 2 3 6 3 6 4 6 5 3 4 5 2 4 2 1 6 3 5 6 3 2 1 4 1 3 6 4 6 6 5 5 5 5 4 2 1 2 3 3 6

Not 6 being diced : 75 times  and Six being diced :25

20% times that six being diced

6 4 6 1 3 5 4 4 1 4 4 1 4 5 6 3 4 3 2 3 3 5 2 1 3 3 2 6 1 3 5 6 5 2 2 6 3 1 2 2 1 6 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 5 4 4 6 2 2 2 2 1 6 3 5 6 5 3 6 6 5 2 4 3 2 6 4 6 6 6 6 3 5 2 3 2 4 4 5 4 2 1 6 1 6 6 3 3 5 2 5 2 5

Not 6 being diced : 80 times  and Six being diced :20

16% times that six being diced

5 4 2 2 4 4 6 2 2 1 3 5 4 2 5 5 6 5 3 3 4 3 3 5 3 1 6 5 3 6 2 4 6 6 5 4 4 6 6 5 6 5 1 3 4 3 2 1 1 6 1 1 4 4 3 3 1 3 5 3 2 6 5 4 4 2 6 4 6 3 1 4 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 5 2 3 3 6 6 2 3 3 5 5 1 1 6 4 6 3 2 2

Not 6 being diced : 83 times  and Six being diced :17

Comment: This answer has a problem.  According to your code, every other number would _always_ be 6.  This is nowhere near what a natural distribution of rolls would be.

Answer (score 0):

Don't roll a six sided die, roll a ten sided die.  The die has sides marked [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6].  Pick a random side for each die roll.